# SAS combining range of class values for PROC MEANS

Tags: sas

I am taking a scripting class and I have no idea what I'm doing!
For my assignment, I am supposed to print min/max/mean/std for each year. The .csv file I was given to use has a year column with the years as

```
1949.083
1949.167
1949.25
1949.333
1949.417
1949.5
1949.583
1949.667
1949.75
1949.833
1949.917
1950
1950.083
1950.167
```

and so on, all the way to 1960.
Assuming I am using PROC MEANS, is there a way to maybe combine the years so I can print a single set of calculations (min/max/mean/std) for each year? As in one set of calculations for the year 1949 (data values from 1949-1949.917), another one for 1950 (data values from 1950-1950.917), etc. Not sure if I'm making sense! I've been looking everywhere for hours and I can't figure it out! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want PROC MEANS to calculate separate statistics per year you can use a CLASS statement.  With a CLASS statement it will define the groups based on the formatted value.  So if you just use the format 4. with the variable YEAR then each value will be mapped to a simple 4 digit value.

```
proc means data=have min max mean std ;
  class year;
  format year 4.;
  var analysis_var ;
run;
```

But that will round values like `1,949.667` to 1950 and not 1949. If you want to ignore the fractional part of the year you can use the INT() function.  So first create a new variable and then use that new variable in the CLASS statement.

```
data step1;
  set have;
  yrnum = int(year);
run;
proc means data=step1 min max mean std ;
  class yrnum ;
  var analysis_var ;
run;
```